# Radio items in GNOME panel applet's context menu

Tags: applet, contextmenu, gnome, menuitem

Is there a way to put radio menu items in a GNOME panel applet's context menu, and then control which of the items is marked as active?  [The official documentation is less than helpful](http://library.gnome.org/devel/panel-applet/stable/applet-popups.html), and all of the applets installed on my computer use normal menu items, so I can't look at their source code for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the XML file defining the context menu, for each radio `<menuitem>` set `type="radio"` and the `group` property to the name of the radio item group, like this:

```
<Root>
  <popups>
    <popup name="button3">
      <menuitem name="Foo" verb="DoFoo" label="Foo is awesome" type="radio" group="mygroup"/>
      <menuitem name="Bar" verb="DoBar" label="Bar is cool" type="radio" group="mygroup"/>
      <menuitem name="Baz" verb="DoBaz" label="Baz rocks" type="radio" group="mygroup"/>
    </popup>
  </popups>
</Root>
```

You don't set up handlers to respond to the items being selected the same way you would for normal menu items.  Instead, you listen for the "ui-event" signal on the BonoboUIComponent for the menu:

```
BonoboUIComponent *component = panel_applet_get_popup_component (applet);
g_signal_connect (component, "ui-event", G_CALLBACK (popup_component_ui_event_cb), NULL);
/* ... */
static void
popup_component_ui_event_cb (BonoboUIComponent *component,
                             const gchar *path,
                             Bonobo_UIComponent_EventType type,
                             const gchar *state_string,
                             gpointer data)
{
}
```

`path` will be the full path (see below) of the item that was clicked.  `state_string` will be the new state value of the item (see below).  There will be two events for each click of a radio item: one to deselect the old item, and one to select the new one.

To manipulate the checked state of the buttons, use `bonobo_ui_component_set_prop` to set the "state" property to "0" (unchecked) or "1" (checked).  To be safe, explicitly uncheck the old value; there are some corner cases where you could otherwise wind up with multiple radio items in the same group checked (particularly if the context menu hasn't yet actually been drawn).

```
BonoboUIComponent *component = panel_applet_get_popup_component (applet);
bonobo_ui_component_set_prop (component, "/commands/Foo", "state", "1", NULL);
bonobo_ui_component_set_prop (component, "/commands/Bar", "state", "0", NULL);
bonobo_ui_component_set_prop (component, "/commands/Baz", "state", "0", NULL);
```

Note that you identify the radio item by "/commands/name", where name is the name you gave the item in the XML file.

You *could* likewise use `bonobo_ui_component_get_prop` to look for which radio item is checked, but you're better off using the event handlers to detect when the user clicks on one.

In general, the [documentation for BonoboUIComponent in libbonoboui](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libbonoboui/stable/libbonoboui-bonobo-ui-component.html) should provide more information about ways to manipulate items in the menu.

Comment: I *knew* I had done this before a while back, but had forgotten how.  I finally found the four-year-old code buried on an external hard drive, which is what I used to derive the above answer.  Given the paucity of views so far, I figured I might as well answer my own question.